# Laravel 4 base/master view

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've recently gotten some problems. There is an model from which I pull some data and things. There is a menu link that I want to be on every page I enter, so I've put it into the base/master view. But the problem is, I need to enter `->with blabla thing` on every public function in every controller. How could I not do that? I mean is there anyway around it? I don't want to do that with thingy on every controller method/function. Here's my code:

```
                    @if ( Auth::guest() )

                <li style="float: right;padding-right: 0">
                  <ul class="nav">
                    <li>
                      <a href="{{ URL::to('register') }}">
                        <i class="icon-black icon-plus">
                        </i>

                        <strong>
                          Register
                        </strong>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="{{ URL::to('login') }}">
                        <i class="icon-black icon-lock">
                        </i>

                        <strong>
                          Log in
                        </strong>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </li>
                </li>
              </ul>

              @else

              <li class="divider-vertical">
              </li>
              <li style="float: right;padding-right: 0">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <div class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="icon-user">
                    </i>
                    {{ (Auth::user()->name) }}
                  </div>

                  <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <span class="icon-caret-down">
                    </span>
                  </a>

                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>

                      <a href="{{ URL::to('account/managment') }}">
                        <i class="icon-user">
                        </i>
                        Account Managment  
                      </a>

                    </li>
                    <li>

                      <a href="{{ URL::to('account/managment/change_credentials') }}">
                        <i class="icon-lock">
                        </i>
                        Change Password
                      </a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="divider">
                    </li>
                    <li>

                      <a href="{{ URL::to('account/logout') }}">
                        <i class="icon-off">
                        </i>
                        Log out
                      </a>

                    </li>

                  </ul>
                </div>

                @endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a View Composer :

```
View::composer(array('your.first.view','your.second.view'), function($view)
{
    $view->with('count', User::count());
});
```

Everytime you call your view, a user count will be bound to it automatically.

Edit:

About where to use it, it's up to you and it depends on your app, but you might use pp/start/global.php if you  don't have a better place to put it. It just have to be executed before your those views.

Comment: What do you mean by user count? I don't think we understood eachother.

Comment: It's just an example. You'll need to use your own code on it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, where should I use this? Also, I'll include this in my master view like: @include('your.view.name') ? Never really used View::composer. Also, I don't need that with in the public function thing(only on several places), but I need it on my menu. How could I do it on only several functions, but my menu is located in my master view. And it asks for that with whenever I enter any page.

Comment: You can put those View::composer() calls in your app/start/global.php. Just edited my code to show you how to use it on more than one view using the same code.

Comment: Sorry for unchecking the answer, but it's not working. The error states: `Trying to get a property of non-object` and displays the View::composer method I implemented. Here's how I did it: `View::composer(array('common.roles'), function($view)
{
 $roles = Auth::user()->type;
    $view->with('roles', $roles);
});`

Comment: You're using Auth::user()->type, you have to be sure the user is logged in first...

Comment: First, try something simpler, like `View::composer(array('common.roles'), function($view) { $roles = 5; $view->with('roles', $roles); });`, then you can go forward with your code. It's working or you wouldn't have an error raised on it.

Comment: I've just implemented the Auth::check() method and it works now. Thank you again:)

Answer (score 1):

@Antonio's answer is a good way to do this. You can also use View::share(); to accomplish this with a shorter code.

```
View::share(array(
    'foo' => 'bar'    
));
```

Comment: Just to remind readers that View::share will make those bindings available to *all* views.